# return array and convert it to list flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
Future<bool> checkLiked(String questionID) async {
    DocumentReference ref = questionBank.doc(questionID);
    List<dynamic>? list;
    await ref.get().then((value) {
      list = value['userLiked'];
    });
    print(list!.contains(uid));
    return list!.contains(uid);
  }
```

it alawys return false also the uid already in the list and when i print the list it empty but inside the then method it contain the uid how to return the list outside the then method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're printing the list outside, but printing the value inside....
**However** both of them won't return the right values because you have to use `.data()` to get the data from the result:

One way

```
Future<bool> checkLiked(String questionID) async {
 DocumentReference ref = questionBank.doc(questionID);

 List<dynamic>? list= (await ref.get()).data()?['userLiked'];

 return list;
}
```

another way

```
Future<bool> checkLiked(String questionID) async {
 DocumentReference ref = questionBank.doc(questionID);
 List<dynamic>? list;
 await ref.get().then((value) {
  list = value.data()['userLiked'];
 });

 return list;  
}
```

Also

```
Future<bool> checkLiked(String questionID) async {
 DocumentReference ref = questionBank.doc(questionID);
 List<dynamic>? list;
 list = await ref.get().then((value) {
  return value.data()['userLiked'];
 });

 return list;  
}
```

And you can assign array to `List<dynamic>` with no casting.

Answer (score 0):

Combining `async`/`await` and `then` is a recipe for problems. You should use either `async`/`await` **or** `then`, not both.

```
Future<bool> checkLiked(String questionID) async {
  DocumentReference ref = questionBank.doc(questionID);
  DocumentSnapshot value = await ref.get();
  List<dynamic>? list = value['userLiked'];
  print(list!.contains(uid));
  return list!.contains(uid);
}
```